# Hibernate Critera query for an OR parent-child association

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am using Hibernate 3.5 and I am trying to do a search that will either return a parent object that contains a keyword or return a parent item if one of it's child objects contains a keyword.

Here is an example using the Cat from the [Hibernate Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en-US/html/index.html):

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="cats")
    public class Cat {
        private String name;
        private Set<Cat> kittens;
    }
```

Here is the sample query from the [Criteria Query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations) section:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add(Restrictions.like("name", "F%")
    .createAlias("kittens", "kits")
    .addRestrictions.like("kits.name", "F%");
List<Cat> cats = criteria.list();
```

This will return only Cat objects where the name of the parent starts with F AND the name of one of the kittens starts with F. I want to create a query to return the logical disjunction of these restrictions. Cats whose names begin with F OR Cats who have kittens whose name begins with F.
Example: (Cat:[Kittens])
Fritz:[], Frank:[Al, Barry],Charlie:[Fran]; Should all be included in the result set. 
While Bob:[] and Mike:[Allen, Bosco] should not.

I have tried a few different queries but have been unable to get the correct results.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCritera(Cat.class)
    .add(Restrictions.like("name", "F%);
```

This query returns all Parent Cats whose name begins with F.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .createAlias("kittens", "kits")
    .add(Restrictions.like("kits.name", "F%");
```

This query returns all Parent Cats who have kittens whose name starts with F.
This is where my trouble begins, I need the disjunction of these two sets. First I tried:

```
Criteria.criteria = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .createAlias("kittens", "kits")
    .add(Restrictions.disjunction()
        .add(Restrictions.like("name", "F%")
        .add(Restrictions.like("kits.name", "F%");
```

This query does not work. It returns only the parents whose children have names that start with F just like the previous query.

```
Criteria.criteria = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .createAlias("kittens", "kits")
    .add(Restrictions.or(
        Restrictions.like("name", "F%"),
        Restrictions.like("kits.name", "F%"));
```

If I'm reading the API documentation correctly this query is the same as the previous query. This would make sense because I get the same results as the previous two queries.

I'm stumped as a way to get the correct set of Cats as a result through a criteria search.

I suppose that I could run two separate queries and then clean up the resulting collection, but that seems needlessly inelegant.

Any suggestions appreciated.
Meow.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Criteria.criteria = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
.createAlias("kittens", "kits", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
.add(Restrictions.or(
    Restrictions.like("name", "F%"),
    Restrictions.like("kits.name", "F%"));
```

That should work.